# S3Client assume role from Kubernetes service account

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-s3

I have a Spring Boot application being migrated from EC2 to EKS. I have a role and policy set up in AWS and that role is attached to a Service Account for the pod.
The application puts objects in S3 and generates pre-signed URLs for objects in the bucket. It uses the older AWS SDK `v1`.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.273</version>
</dependency>
```

and sets up an S3Client like so:

```java
AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(awsRegion)
                .enablePathStyleAccess()
                .enablePayloadSigning()
                .withCredentials(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(true))
                .build();
```

When deployed on EC2, the policy works and has permissions to interact with S3. However, when deployed to EKS, I get 403s from S3:

```
S3 failed with an error.  No link will be generated.
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: xxxxxxxx; S3 Extended Request ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; Proxy: null)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1879)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1418)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1387)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1157)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:814)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:781)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:755)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:561)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:541)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5456)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5403)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1372)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1346)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesObjectExist(AmazonS3Client.java:1427)
```

and I see in the AWS console that the role is not being used. Since the Service Account for the pod correctly has the role, my assumption is the application cannot assume the role, hence the 403s.

I assume that the Credentials Provider in the S3ClientBuilder needs to change. What kind of credentials provider is needed in the S3Client to assume the role from the Service Account on the pod? Is this possible without moving to the newer `v2` SDK (still may migrate, but would I have the same issue?)

Comment: Make sure you have the `-sts` dependency and then just remove the `.withCredentials()`. The default provider chain *should* do the right thing.

Comment: @jordanm this worked, throw this up as an answer if you'd like. I'm curious though, where in the default provider chain does this get picked up? All I see set is AWS_ROLE_ARN and AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE, is this step 3 here? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html

Comment: Yep, the k8s service account auth is `3. Web Identity Token credentials`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jordanm for the answer - on EKS, the

```
.withCredentials(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(true))
```

is not needed. The default credentials provider chain picks up on the `AWS_ROLE_ARN` and `AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE`.